# Show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx$ is Lebesgue integrable using MCT

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

The goal is to show that while $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx$ does not exist as a Riemann integral, it is easily defined as a Lebesgue integral with Monotone Convergence Theorem (MCT).

I'm having some trouble understanding the intuition of using MCT here and how it is properly applied.

Given $f(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx$, we can define
$$
g_{k}(x) = 
\begin{cases}
    e^{-x} & x \leq k \\
    0 & x > k
\end{cases}
$$
and use monotone convergence.
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx = \underset{k \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\int_{0}^{\infty}g_{k}(x)dx = \underset{k \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\left[-e^{-x}\right]_{0}^{k} = \underset{k \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\left[-e^{-k} + 1\right] = 1
$$
Assuming this is the proper approach (of which I'm not sure), why even define the piecewise function?  How would we show this is not Riemann integrable?

Comment: The function is not (properly) Riemann-integrable, because by definition RIemann-integrability requires bounded functions on a compact interval. However, it is improperly Riemann-integrable, and the improper RIemann integral coincides with the Lebesgue integral. Also, your proof here is weird, you never write $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}$ anywhere. It should be $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\,dx=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\int_0^{\infty}g_k\,dx=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}[-e^{-x}]_0^k=1$.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah I wrote the proof a bit hastily.  Assume the edit looks good?  Got it, I was aware of improper Riemann integrals so was a bit unsure whether that still means the function was not Riemann integrable.  Do you know why the piecewise definition even matters here?  Like why is it important that we explicitly define the case $0$ for $x > k$?

Comment: The piecewise definition is there only because usually the (Riemann/Lebesgue) FTC (which is what one is **really** using to evaluate integrals concretely) is often stated for compact intervals.